# Importing dump using impdp command throws ORA-39083, ORA-29958 and ORA-00959

Tags: oracle, import, oracle11g

While importing a dump into our server we got the following error message. We have done the dump import lots of times previously but we have never faced such an issue. Both the servers are using Oracle 11.2.0.4.0

After doing lot of googling we are unable to fix it. Please help.

```
ORA-39083: Object type INDEX failed to create with error:
ORA-29958: fatal error occurred in the execution of ODCIINDEXCREATE routine
ORA-00959: tablespace '' does not exist
Failing sql is:
CREATE INDEX "ABC"."IDX_TEST_PROJECT_XML" ON "ABC"."TEST_PROJECTS" ("XML_INFO")  
    INDEXTYPE IS "XDB"."XMLINDEX"  PARAMETERS ('path table test_project_xptab
    paths ( include ( /Project/Children ) )')PARALLEL 1 
Job "ABC"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" completed with 1 error(s) at Thu Apr 14 18:46:45 2016 elapsed 0 01:40:55
```

Comment: Is this the first time you've used Data Pump with an XML Index?

Comment: No we have used data pump to import dump with XML data type lot of times in the same server for which we have raised the issue for.

Comment: Does the destination database has same tablespaces as the source?

Comment: We have used "REMAP_TABLESPACE=sourcetablespacename:destinationtablespace name" Thank you APC & Chomel for pitching in to help.

Comment: I take it the space in "REMAP_TABLESPACE=sourcetablespacename:destinationtablespace name" is a typo.